# Excel Macro to open link and then snap back to sheet

Tags: excel, cell, vba

I am having trouble recording an excel macro that accesses a relative cell, opening a link within that cell, and then returns to excel.

For example I need to describe an image in cell A1, the link to the image is in cell A3.
I want to use a keyboard shortcut to run a macro that opens the link in cell A3 and then returns me to cell A1 so that I can type in a description.

I am guessing this is really simple but I have next to no experience with Excel, thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just incorporate use of `HYPERLINK` function that is available in Excel?